# An application of the Paley-Wiener theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, laplace-transform, fourier-transform, spectral-theory, entire-functions

Extract of an article:

"the Laplace transform of $T(t)f$ is an entire function and since the resolvent is meromorphic of finite exponential type it must be of finite exponential type, say $\nu$, too. **An application of the Paley-Wiener theorem [2, 6.9.1] now yields
$$\int_0^{\infty} e^{-zt} T(t)f \, dt=\int_0^{\nu} e^{-zt} T(t)f \, dt.$$**"

The notations are as follows:

- $T(t)$ is the semigroup of an operator $A$ on a Hilbert space $H \ni f$, so that the Laplace transform of $T(t)f$, i.e. $\int_0^{\infty} e^{-zt} T(t)f \, dt$, is equal to the resolvent $(z-A)^{-1}f$ for $z$ large.
  In this article, the resolvent is assumed beforehand to be meromorphic of finite exponential type and $f$ is assumed to be such that $z \mapsto (z-A)^{-1}f$ is entire.
- The reference [2] is Boas "Entire functions" and the theorem 6.9.1 is the following: " Let $f(z)=\int_a^b e^{izt} g(t) \, dt$, where $g(t)$ is integrable, $|a| \leq b$, and $g(t)$ does not vanish almost everywhere in any neighborhood of $b$; then $f(z)$ is an entire function of order $1$ and type $b$ (and not of smaller type)."

I have no idea how the author uses the theorem of this reference. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The whole statement treats $T(t)f$ as one function with certain properties, so the semigroup stuff should be irrelevant, the same should hold for any $g:=T(t)f$ with the same properties. Now the Paley-Wiener theorem (some version of it, see wikipedia) says if $g$ is of exponential type $\nu$, then its Fourier transform has compact support in $[-\nu, \nu]$. This is almost what you have, but there seems to be an $i$ missing, maybe hidden in the definition of $z$?

Comment: Let $\bar{g}$ be the ext. of $g$ by zero in $(-\infty,0)$.
Let $r(z)=\int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{-zt} \bar{g}(t) \,dt$.
We want to prove that $r(z)=\int_{-\nu}^{\nu} e^{-zt} \bar{g}(t) \, dt$, i.e. $\tilde{r}(\xi)=\int_{-\nu}^{\nu} e^{i \xi t} \bar{g}(t) \, dt$, where $\tilde{r}(\xi)=r(-i\xi)$.
To apply PW we need $\tilde{r} \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ but, if we go back to the original notation, this requires an estimation of $(-i\xi-A)^{-1}$ for $\xi \in \mathbb{R}$, which we don't have in general (from semigp theory we only know $||(\lambda-A)^{-1}|| \leq M/(\Re \lambda-\omega)$).

Comment: @quarague We need to assume $\int_0^{\infty} e^{-zt} T(t)f $ is $L^2$ or something of the same strength on all vertical lines not only $\Re(z) > \log \|T(1)\|$ otherwise it is much more complicated.